# Automate the installation of .run package

Tags: software-installation

I would like to automate in a single command execution the installation of .run file (xampp in this case) which requires interactive answer from user:

**Here is the manual installation:**

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Welcome to the XAMPP Setup Wizard.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select the components you want to install; clear the components you do not want 
to install. Click Next when you are ready to continue.

XAMPP Core Files : **Y** (Cannot be edited)

XAMPP Developer Files [Y/n] :**n**

Is the selection above correct? [Y/n]: **Y**

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installation Directory

XAMPP will be installed to /opt/lampp
Press **[Enter]** to continue:

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Setup is now ready to begin installing XAMPP on your computer.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: **Y**

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please wait while Setup installs XAMPP on your computer.

 Installing
 0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
 #########################################

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Setup has finished installing XAMPP on your computer.
```

How can I pre-set the following user entry from the beginning without user intervention?
Y
N
Y
[enter]
Y

Comment: [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks HalosGhost. Looks like expect is the right direction.

Comment: You can use Option file. I used to do Microstrategy application silent installation via option.txt

Answer (score 0):

There is the mysterious

```
 --optionfile <optionfile>      Installation option file
```

with no documentation I could find (which would be combined with `--mode unattended`).

Otherwise, I've had some success with the hackish `echo -e "YNY\nY" | <command>` where `<command>` will be `sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run`. (N.B. I've done the installing EMC Networker, not XAMPP.)